# Where clause followed by FirstOrDefault returning the same value

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-server-2012

I have a class that has a function something like this:

```
public string Code { get; set; }

public Dal.Foo GetFoo(Dal.MyContext ctx)
{
    var obj = ctx.Foos.Where(f => f.Code == this.Code).FirstOrDefault();
    return obj;
}
```

Now this works fine usually. However, I another function in another class that calls it like this:

```
using (var ctx = new Dal.MyContext())
{
    var curr = parameters.Current.GetFoo(ctx);
    var target = parameters.Target.GetFoo(ctx);
    // ...
}
```

And the problem is that `Current` and `Target` are definitely different objects, they definitely have different values for `Code`, but when I execute this code, I'm ending up with the same object for `curr` and `target`!?! `curr == target` returns `true` which it *really* shouldn't. I even looked at the SQL generated from the `GetFoo` method, and it correctly calls the database with different parameters, and executing those commands in SQL Server Management Studio returns two different results as expected. I can fix the problem by not giving them the same context (i.e. putting the second call in it's own `using` block with a new `MyContext`), but that really shouldn't be necessary.

What's going on here?

Edit: Not sure if this is relevant or not, but I should mention that I'm actually hitting a view and not a table on the SQL server. Nevertheless, it's still producing SQL that looks correct and passes in the right parameter for the `Where` clause.

Another Edit:

I tried adding this after the line that gets `obj`:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(obj.Code == this.Code);
```

It passes on the first call and fails on the second. Which seems like it shouldn't be possible.

Comment: As far as I can see, you are accessing the same object `Foos` of the same context `ctx`, independently of `Current` and `Target`. Why would it differ from itself?

Comment: @Thaoden, notice that he is filtering by `this.Code`, which will hold separate values for separate instances of class

Comment: @Matt Burland, in Debug mode when you have breakpoint on 
`var obj = ctx.Foos.Where(f => f.Code == this.Code).FirstOrDefault();` is everything correct there? Do you see different codes? Also do you see different return objects on return line? May be you better post how  you are creating your classes?  Also `and fails on the second` can you add exception thrown?

Comment: Which EF version, is it ?
have you tried removing `this.Code` from the linq query and use a local variable with value of this.code ?

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri: Yes they are different codes. I can hover over them and see different values for `this.Code`. I can also see different SQL generated by using `ctx.Database.Log = s => System.Diagnostics.WriteLine(s)`. The exception is just an assertion failed exception that you'd expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok - I think I tracked down the problem. @GertArnold's answer helped me find the cause. The problem was that, for whatever reason, when I imported the view into Entity Framework, EF decided that two other (and unrelated) fields in the database should be used to construct the key and not `Code` (which is actually the key). I set `Entity Key` to `True` in the `edmx` file and now it's working as expected.

I guess because, as far as EF was concerned, I hadn't changed the primary key, it was fine to return the same object even though it didn't actually match the `Where` criteria. The whole SQL it generated was horribly misleading and confusing because I guess it was never actually executed anyway.

Comment: @GertArnold: I will when I can (unless I forget, which I might).

Answer (score 1):

An Entity Framework context is an [identity map](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/identityMap.html), i.e. it keeps a *single* copy of each entity in the database. Even when an object is re-fetched from the database, EF doesn't modify the values in the local copy. I think this is because it would interfere with change tracking and it could overwrite client-side changes that were made in the mean time.

So it's by design that `curr == target` and that `Code` is always the first value fetched from the database, unless it was modified in client code (in which case `curr` and `target` both would obviously have the modified value).

Comment: If we consider simple console app, that just creates context and then selects 2 orders from thet context with different IDs, do you want to say that both object will be the same?

Comment: I don't doubt that this is tied up with the identity map, but it still doesn't make a lick of sense that I can't make two calls on the same context passing different values to the where clause and get two *different* objects. In the second case, the object returned doesn't even satisfy the `Where` clause when it was retrieved.

Comment: @MattBurland You're right. That doesn't make sense. By your finding `curr == target` I concluded that the different parameters did indeed produce the same result (which is possible after all). This is also the kind of problem that may occur if EF doesn't have an appropriate primary key for the view, i.e. a key consisting of a combination of fields that's guaranteed to be unique.

Comment: It looks like the problem was with what EF thought the key should actually be versus what it was supposed to be. I upvoted you because your comment about identity maps did point me in the direction of thinking about what it was using as a key. I'm still not sure it really makes sense to me because the `Where` clause clearly wasn't satisfied, but marking `Code` as `EntityKey` does seem to fix this particular problem.

Comment: Ah, glad you found it!